# Generation of simple, CSS-less HTML with htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, css

When `htlatex` converts a document, emphasis and bold-face are converted to spans of a certain style which is defined in the accompanying CSS file.

Input:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
  Normal text

  \em{Emphasized text}

  \textbf{Bold-faced text}
\end{document}
```

Output (header and footer stripped):

```html
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" >Normal text
<!--l. 6--><p class="indent" >  <span 
class="cmti-10x-x-109">Emphasized text</span>
<!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >  <span 
class="cmbxti-10x-x-109">Bold-faced text </span>
```

Is it possible to generate "plain" HTML that does not use an external CSS file? Something along these lines:

```html
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" >Normal text
<!--l. 6--><p class="indent" >  <em>Emphasized text</em>
<!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >  <b>Bold-faced text </b>
```

This is for pasting references into another website that already has a CSS.

Comment: You can also include the css-code inside the html file. Would that be acceptable too?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to do two things:

you can disable generation of css and ugly elements like

```html
<span 
class="cmti-10x-x-109">Emphasized text</span>
```

with some command line options:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml,NoFonts,-css"
```

You will then have to provide configurations for `em` and `textit`, as they are by default dealt only by css.

This should be done with custom config file, like `myfonts.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Now your htlatex call will be

```
htlatex filename "myfonts,-css,NoFonts"
```

Resulting html

```html
<body 
>
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" >Normal text
</p><!--l. 6--><p class="indent" >  <em>Emphasized text</em>
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >  <b>Bold-faced text</b> </p> 
</body></html>
```

All command line options of `tex4ht` are described in [this article](http://www.cvr.cc/?p=504#more-504). There are also other interesting articles about configuring of this system.

For getting rid of `<p class="indent">`, you can put following to the config file:

```
\Configure{HtmlPar}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
```

Comment: Works for me. But I have two questions: 1. Where did you find the documentation on the -css option? 2. Is there a way to get rid of the `class="indent"`?

Comment: @user946850 see edit

Comment: The described code works for me too. But how to get rid off 

         class="likesectionHead"
and 

     <a id="x1-1000"></a>

from the < h3> tag (similarly from the < h4> tag), of the resulting html:

         <h3 class="likesectionHead"><a id="x1-1000"></a>2013</h3>
         <p>
         </p> 

         <h4 class="likesubsectionHead"><a id="x1-2000"></a>Journal papers</h4>
         <p>
         </p>

Comment: On my system (WinXP + MixTex), I must give options without spaces in between, as "myfonts,-css,NoFonts" instead of "myfonts, -css, NoFonts".  Since I just wasted a lot of time to find this out I thought it might be useful to have this here.

Comment: @EmanueleViola it works with spaces on Linux, but it is obviously better to not include them. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
htlatex myfile.tex "html,css-in"
```

This will embed css into the html file.

Note that, you may need to execute the command two times because the "css-in" option uses the .css file generated in the previous call.