# Producing unformatted html with tex4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, html

When using tex4ht, a formatted html file is obtained. It uses a css file and multiple classes such as

```
<span class="ec-lmbx-10x-x-109">toto</span>
```

However, when using a Content Management System (CMS) such as Joomla, such formatting classes are not desired since all the formatting is handled by the CMS. A clean html file is preferred with html tags such as < H3>, < H4>, ... but without formatting classes for each tag.

Is it possible to obtain, with tex4ht, such a clean html file with no formatting classes but only with formatting html tags?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70059/2891

Comment: This reference has partly answered the question. However, I did not figure out how to eliminate the classes of < H3> and < H4> tags.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: How to produce as clean output from `tex4ht` as possible is described in another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70061/2891). This answer is about further cleaning of the output.

Some things are rather difficult to modify in `tex4ht`. Easier is sometimes to use `xslt` styles to modify the output.

This fragment:

```xml
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1</span> <a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>hello world</h3>
```

Can be with this style

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   >
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration = "yes" method="xml" />


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:h3|xhtml:h4|xhtml:h5">
<xsl:copy> 
<xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="xhtml:a/@id" /></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:h3/xhtml:a|xhtml:h4/xhtml:a|xhtml:h5/xhtml:a" />
<xsl:template match="xhtml:h3/xhtml:span|xhtml:h4/xhtml:span|xhtml:h5/xhtml:span">
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Translated as

```xml
<h3 id="x1-10001">1 hello world</h3>
```

I used `id` parameter so one can easily make link to the section,