# Export LaTeX to HTML using .gif for equations?

Tags: tex4ht, png, htlatex, latex2html, gif

I try to make help files for my wxWidgets-based software. wxWidgets supports displaying simple html pages and i use `htlatex` executable tool to convert my `.tex` to `.html`, where equations are rendered as pictures.
I learned that i can make `.cfg` file to edit latex4ht's compilation settings. For example i need to convert inline equations to images too and i also would like to have .gif images on output instead of `.png`, so i made this **mycfg.cfg** file:

```
\Preamble{html}
\begin{document}
\Configure{Picture}{.gif}
\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
\Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class=’’math’’; align=’’absmiddle’’}
\EndPreamble
```

And i invoke htlatex like this: `htlatex samplefile.tex "mycfg"`.

Everything goes smooth, but there is no `.gif` files. I can see on the end of logs strings like this:

> ```
> l. 90 Writing samplefile.idv[1] (samplefile0x.gif)
> l. 92 Writing samplefile.idv[2] (samplefile1x.gif)
> l. 99 Writing samplefile.idv[3] (samplefile2x.gif)
> l. 104 Writing samplefile.idv[4] (samplefile3x.gif)
> ```

And there is `samplefile.idv` on output, but i do not know how to extract .gifs from .idv files.
Also i would like to get rid of CSS on output. Is it possible to get HTML files without CSS?

**UPD**: Maybe i'm doing it wrong (trying to get .gif images). Inside the `.log` file i can also read:

> --- Note --- for gif bitmaps of pictures, use the 'gif' command line option. (Character bitmaps are controled only by 'g' records of tex4ht.env and '-g' switches of tex4ht.c)

But i do not know how to include this command-line option. Tried `htlatex myfile "gif"`, it does not work.

Comment: Something along the lines of `htlatex -gif` would be a more usual way to specify the option, or `htlatex --gif` if it behaves more properly! (But I haven't tested this mostly on the grounds that I consider it a minor miracle any I persuade tex4ht to output anything for me at all.)

Comment: @cfr I tried the way supposed in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70061/52547) `htlatex smaplefile.tex "mycfg, -css, gif"` but it still generates css style and does not change image format.

Answer (score 4):

Your configuration file is correct, in the log file you can see that gif images were requested. `idv` file is a special `dvi` file, where only images to be converted are stored. Actual configuration for image conversion is stored in file `tex4ht.env`. Different versions of this file exist for `unix` and `windows`. By default, conversion is done by `dvips` and `imagemagick`, so maybe in you case this fails because you don't have some of this tools installed?

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43801/2891) for some information how to configure `tex4ht.env` file. You may at first copy this file to your current dir, so you don't break anything. I think you should try to use `dvipng` for conversion, so you have to find `<dvipng>` section and add spaces before `<dvipng>` and `</dvipng>`, and then comment out `<convert>` section, by removing spaces at the beginning and end of the section.

Example of `<dvipng>` section:

```
 <dvipng>
G.png 
Gdvipng -T tight -x 1400 -D 72 -bg Transparent -pp %%2:%%2 %%1 -o %3
G.gif 
Gdvipng -T tight -x 1400 -D 72 -bg Transparent -gif -pp %%2:%%2 %%1 -o %%3 
G.
Gdvips -Ppdf -mode ibmvga -D 110 -f %%1 -pp %%2 > zz%%4.ps
Gconvert -crop 0x0 -density 110x110 -transparent '#FFFFFF' zz%%4.ps %%3
Grm zz%%4.ps
 </dvipng>
```