# htlatex-produced HTML does not center correctly

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

If I run htlatex on

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla bla

\begin{center} x \end{center} \end{document}
```

with the setting in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70059/generation-of-simple-css-less-html-with-htlatex) I get the code below, but my browser (mozilla firefox) does not properly center "x".  How can I redefine the way that center is handled to just use some simple html tag (which my browser does understand correctly)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   >  
<head> 
<title></title> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
 <meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
 <meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />  
<!-- -css,NoFonts,html,xhtml --> 
 <meta name="src" content="a.tex" /> 
 <meta name="date" content="2016-10-16 19:12:00" /> 
</head>
<body  > 
<p>Bla bla bla bla    </p>   
<div class="center"  > 
<p> </p> 
 <p>x</p>  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using code answering a question that explicitly asks that the css that produces the style is _not_ generated, so in this case you need to provide the css for the `.center` class to centre the text. Or use the default setting and let tex4ht generate the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centering is done by `CSS`, so it can't work if you disable it's use in the document. `<center>` tag exists, which is deprecated in HTML 5, but you can try to use it, if you really don't want to use `CSS`.

Try the following `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,-css,NoFonts}

\def\FinishPar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}
\ConfigureEnv{center}{}{}{\FinishPar\HCode{<center>}}{\FinishPar\HCode{</center>}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

Options `-css,NoFonts` are included in the config file, so you don't have to specify them on the command line anymore. `\FinishPar` is helper macro to close paragraph tags at correct places. `\ConfigureEnv` can be used to configure environments. Because `center` environment is implemented using list, is is necessary to pass the custom tags in fourth and fifth arguments of `\ConfigureEnv`.

The other way would be to provide custom CSS file, `hello.css`:

```
div.center{
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

and the `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,-css,NoFonts}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hello.css" />\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This example just add link to the custom `CSS` file to the document.

The result looks the same for both possibilities:

[image]