# Proper enumerate with tex4ht/make4ht and no css style sheet

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I'm attempting to convert a LaTeX document of mine as no-style sheet html to be copy-pasted as a (Wordpress) blog post (thus the css-less requirement). So, I've started from michal.h21's instructions at [Generation of simple, CSS-less HTML with htlatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70061/105447). Things work mostly fine, but I still have some problems with enumerate environments, which get a line break between the label and the item text.

My settings are the following:

> `.make4ht` (just to set the .cfg file):

```
set_settings{tex4ht_sty_par = "filename," .. settings.tex4ht_sty_par}
```

> `filename.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}

\Configure{HtmlPar}
    {\EndP\Tg<p>}
    {\EndP\Tg<p>}
    {\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
    {\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

> the build file `filename.mk4`:

```
settings_add{ tex4ht_sty_par =  ",xhtml,NoFonts,-css" }
Make:latexmk()
```

> and the file itself `filename.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=4em, itemsep=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{wide, labelindent=0pt, label={Part \Roman* --}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{wide=1em, label={\arabic* --}, resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A first item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item A first subitem in enumerate
  \item A second one
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this with:

```
make4ht -uf html5+tidy filename.tex
```

The result is:

[image]

How could I get rid of these line breaks between the label and the item text in the enumerate environments?

(Side note: comments on the overall procedure and the used settings for the purpose at hand would also be welcome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @michal.h21's comments, I was able to reach a solution to this.
My initial attempt had been to get the relevant list configuration settings from the `tex4ht` folder, and adapt them to my purposes in my own config file. But I could then not build my document.

However, as Michal taught me, those files commonly use `:` in macros names, which cannot be ported without due care. With that information in hand, I could then reach the desired results with the following settings:

> A build file `filename.mk4`:

```
set_settings{tex4ht_sty_par = "filename," .. settings.tex4ht_sty_par}
settings_add{ tex4ht_sty_par =  ",NoFonts,-css" }
Make:latexmk()
```

> A config file `filename.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{html5}

\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}

\Configure{HtmlPar}
    {\EndP\Tg<p>}
    {\EndP\Tg<p>}
    {\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
    {\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}


\catcode`\:=11

    \ConfigureList{enumerate}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<dl \a:LRdir class="enumerate-enumitem">}%
      \PushMacro\end:itm
\global\let\end:itm=\empty}
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\EndP\HCode{</dd></dl>}\ShowPar}
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</dd>}\HCode{<dt
        class="enumerate-enumitem"  style="float:left; clear:left; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em; padding-top:5px;">}\bgroup \bf}
   {\egroup\EndP\HCode{</dt><dd\Hnewline class="enumerate-enumitem" style="padding-top:5px;">}}

\catcode`\:=12

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

(Note the definition of `\ConfigureList{enumerate}` was taken from `html4.4ht` and only the style settings were added, directly within the tags of interest).

> The file itself `filename.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=4em, itemsep=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{wide, labelindent=0pt, label={Part \Roman* --}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{wide=1em, label={\arabic* --}, resume}

\newlist{biblio}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[biblio]{label=\textbullet}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A first item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item A first subitem in enumerate
  \item A second one
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Built with `make4ht -uf html5+tidy filename.tex` will result in:

[image]

From the following html code:

```
<body>
<dl class="enumerate-enumitem">
<dt class="enumerate-enumitem" style="float:left; clear:left; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em; padding-top:5px;">Part I –</dt>
<dd class="enumerate-enumitem" style="padding-top:5px;">A first item
<dl class="enumerate-enumitem">
<dt class="enumerate-enumitem" style="float:left; clear:left; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em; padding-top:5px;">1 –</dt>
<dd class="enumerate-enumitem" style="padding-top:5px;">A first subitem in enumerate</dd>
<dt class="enumerate-enumitem" style="float:left; clear:left; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em; padding-top:5px;">2 –</dt>
<dd class="enumerate-enumitem" style="padding-top:5px;">A second one
<ul class="itemize1">
<li class="itemize">Itemize item</li>
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
</dd>
</dl>
</body>
```

Which can now be properly copy-pasted in a blog post in Wordpress (for it is both css-less and headless).

**Previous answer**

> This works to produce a no-css html, but is not yet good enough, because the style settings are set in the html file head, so when copying to a wordpress blog post these settings were lost. But I keep it here for this might be useful for other purposes (and, strictly speaking, it does answer the OP).

I think I managed a reasonable solution to this (though in not a very useful form for my intended purpose). In no way I could tweak the html tags to get a description list to work without some styling (it doesn't mean it can't be done...). I also could not get the `tex4ht` option `css-in` to actually embed the style sheet in my html file. So I had somehow to bring the style manually to my file. I built the document with defaults letting it thus give me a css style sheet, where I found:

```
dt.enumerate-enumitem{float:left; clear:left; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em;}
```

So, I added to my config file:

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style>
dt.enumerate-enumitem{float:left; clear:left; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em;}
</style>}}
```

And then ran things with option `-css`. The result is satisfactory:

[image]

In detail, my settings for this are:

> A build file `filename.mk4`

```
set_settings{tex4ht_sty_par = "filename," .. settings.tex4ht_sty_par}
settings_add{ tex4ht_sty_par =  ",NoFonts,-css" }
Make:latexmk()
```

> A config file `filename.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{html5}

\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}

\Configure{HtmlPar}
    {\EndP\Tg<p>}
    {\EndP\Tg<p>}
    {\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
    {\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style>
dt.enumerate-enumitem{float:left; clear:left; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em;}
</style>}}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

> The file itself `filename.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=4em, itemsep=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{wide, labelindent=0pt, label={Part \Roman* --}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{wide=1em, label={\arabic* --}, resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A first item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item A first subitem in enumerate
  \item A second one
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Itemize item
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Built with:

```
make4ht -uf html5+tidy filename.tex
```

Comment: I still welcome comments though.  ;-)

Comment: Alas, while this works for a standalone html, it doesn't for copy-pasted html in Wordpress, because the `<head>` is trimmed in the process...

Comment: isn't it possible to include the CSS file generated by tex4ht in the Wordpress template?

Comment: @michal.h21 Thank you for your comment. There are ways (which I haven't yet looked into) to define styles in Wordpress (I'm with wordpress.com not on a self hosted wordpress.org, though. Which means I don't really know how flexible things will really be). But I'm really looking for a "self sufficient" alternative. It would be enough to add a "style" directive inside the `<dt>` tag (I've tested a manual change). But I can't seem to convince `tex4ht` to do so.

Comment: @michal.h21 On a general note. I looked into the corresponding `\ConfigureList` definitions inside the tex4ht directory. I tried to copy some of them to my config file to adjust them. But usually, when I do so, the build process fails. What's the catch?

Comment: it is possible that configurations from `.4ht` files contains commands with `:` as a part of their names. this can cause compilation errors as this character is not normally part of command names.

Comment: @michal.h21 I see. I'll investigate further, to see if I can avoid the failure. But where then are those commands with `:` defined? And what is their scope?

Comment: the `4ht` files enable `:` in command names. they can be used with `\csname ...\endcsname` in normal TeX code.

Comment: anyway, the itemize marks are removed with `\DeleteMark`, which I think standard definitions contain

Comment: @michal.h21 Indeed. The definitions I tried to copy contain commands with `:`. Thanks!  The general procedure would then be to copy those definitions and put any such commands between `\csname ...\endcsname`? Or is there a smarter/better way?

Comment: it is also possible to change catcode of `:` to letter at the begin of the .cfg file, just don't forget to change it back to "other" at the end

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks again! I'll try it here. But if you had any handy pointers on this procedure, that'd be also appreciated.

Comment: I will try to post my answer to this question, but I cannot say when. in a few days hopefully.

Comment: @michal.h21 I did figure it out following your suggestions. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/dd2132e8c2846dd3d3836cdef96a2757. I'd be glad to hear your thoughts on the matter, without any hurry, of course. You can use the gist in your answer if you whish, as it is of your doing. I'd be glad to accept it. And, once again, thanks!